# IPv4 to IPv6 address translation in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy, ipv6, ipv4

I have a Windows 7 PC connected to a IPv6 network. On the PC I have an application that needs to communicate with another IPv6 machine. The application can only be configured with an IPv4 address. Is it possible in Windows 7 to translate an IPv4 packets to be sent using IPv6.

Example:

Windows 7 PC is ::1:1:1. Application is configured to connect to 1.2.3.4.
Remote machine is ::1:1:2.

If possible I would like my Windows 7 PC to translate all TCP messages to 1.2.3.4 on port 567 to be sent to ::1:1:2 on port 567 and all incoming messages and responses from :1:1:2 port 567 to be forwarded to the application as received form 1.2.3.4?

Comment: i suggest you to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling

Comment: @FranciscoTapia, Teredo offers the opposite from the question.  The question has IPv6 connectivity, but there are applications that are IPv4 only.  Teredo gives clients who only have IPv4 internet access to the IPv6 internet.

Comment: @Kaze, will your application accept a hostname instead of an IP address.  You could resolve this with DNS/hosts file.

Comment: @heavyd you right!!

Comment: I would prefer not to use tunneling like Teredo, but do the translation on the transmitting PC. I do not think my application supports IPv6, so using the hostname will not work.

Comment: I have been looking for a proxy solution where the windows machine would take IPv4 traffic from a certain IPv4 address and port at translate it to IPv6. Is there a tool that can do this?